# Android Device Vanishing

Tags: android

I have a really serious problem which is preventing me from doing Android development at work, which I have a strong imperative to get fixed as quickly as possible.

So, I plug in my phone to my OS X machine. I go to the terminal and I do this:

```
rutski@imac:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
3331833A243A00EC    device
```

Now, that looks good so far. But if I do some work for a few minutes I'll eventually get an error somewhere during "adb install", and when I run "adb devices" again I see that now the device is NO LONGER THERE!

So I unplug the phone, and plug it back in. I run "adb devices" and see the device back again, expect the cycle will repeat, and it will reliably disappear after a few minutes.

But it gets better. DDMS for me is completely unusable. I open up an OS X terminal and run "ddms" from the command line. A window pops open with a device list, and my device is there. However, if I so much as click on my device, it will vanish from the list, and I'll get this in the terminal window:

```
08:26:05 E/EventLog: device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.runLogService(AdbHelper.java:469)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.runEventLogService(AdbHelper.java:445)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.runEventLogService(Device.java:290)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.log.event.EventLogPanel$8.run(EventLogPanel.java:454)
```

Yes, I've made sure that USB debugging is enabled. I've done a start-server kill-server with adb. I've rebooted both the phone and my machine several times. Nothing fixes the problem.

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
I just noticed that after rebooting my machine things are stable until I run an app that crashes via something like calling a method on a null object; that's when the device first vanishes from DDMS, and it is flakey forever after. Still, I'm confused about what to do here. I need to be able to debug crashes, and they will happen.

Comment: Dodgy usb connection - either cable to port, or the port on the motherboard? If you plug in the usb cable to charge the phone, then move the cable around gently, does the charing light go on and off?

Comment: what device do you have ? In some cases you should do some settings control panel-> device manager->phone , and her eyou add the usb driver from andorid directory (i think that it is extras- google - usb driver )

Comment: I've tried every USB port on this machine, to no effect. Moving the cable around doesn't change the charger light. Furthermore, I just set up a linux machine, and things work fine over there. The fact that it starts flaking out only after a null-object-deref makes me think it's a software problem, especially since things work fine on my linux box. Still open to thoughts though.